# Python: Group output of Column based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
#code source
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=50,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=10,
                           shuffle=True)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


values = [i for i,x in enumerate(df['Class']) if x == 0]
print(values)
```

The output is

> [5, 6, 9, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 31, 32, 34,
> 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49]

I am trying to group the above output based on the condition that numbers come in **concurrent value** . Such as the output should be:

> Group 1: 5,6
>
> Group 2: 9
>
> Group 3: 11
>
> Group 4: 13,14
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> Group n: 23,24,25,26,27

I am grouping them to have an understanding of the gaps in the column, instead of having a slab of values following each other in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need `Series`, get differences by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.gt.html) and last create groups by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to new `Series` which is used as `by` argument of `groupby`:

```
values = [5, 6, 9, 11, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 
          24, 25, 26, 27, 31, 32, 34, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49]
s = pd.Series(values)
s1 = s.groupby(s.diff().gt(1).cumsum() + 1).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
print (s1)
1                5,6
2                  9
3                 11
4              13,14
5              17,18
6              20,21
7     23,24,25,26,27
8              31,32
9                 34
10             41,42
11       44,45,46,47
12                49
dtype: object
```

Comment: the idea is to communicate the gaps in a representative way, such as group labels for example. I think this output complicates it a bit

Comment: Ok, I try run your code and no `df`, can you add it?

Comment: ah man sorry ! I edited the code and deleted df by mistake, kindly check update

Comment: all hail to the great jezrael !